# Firefox cursor invisible, becomes visible when clicking anything else

Tags: firefox, focus, contenteditable

I have the absolutely strangest bug I've ever encountered, and I'm near my wit's end on this one.  Anyone with ideas on how to debug this (or any clever workarounds) would be awesome.

The problem:

I'm making a simple WYSIWYG editor in Firefox using contenteditable.  The problem appears when I load the text to edit via ajax.  Before the load, the cursor appears fine (for a split second), and once the text loads it disappears.  You can still enter text, and the cursor is definitely still "there" (a status box shows the current line/col just fine), but the cursor is not visible and the selection overlay does not appear.

Here's what makes this really strange:  clicking ANYWHERE, on any other dom element, on firebug, even on another window -- makes the cursor return and behave like normal.  In fact, the only time the cursor has any problems is at the very beginning, when initially loading the page or on refresh.  Clicking anywhere inside the contentedtiable div does not fix it -- you have to click outside for it to refresh.

Right now, I just need a workaround.  I've tried 500 flavors of $(someelement).click or $(somelement).focus, but they don't fully replicate an "actual" click from a user.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  Thanks.

Comment: Firefox has had and doubtless still has huge problems with the caret disappearing in various circumstances. Best you can hope for is trial and error to find a workaround for your particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I didn't find out what is causing the problem, but I found a quick-and-dirty fix does the trick.  I just append an anchor tag to the DOM, focus it (using jQuery .focus), and then remove it.

I tried .focus many times before, but I always tried it on div or li elements, which didn't do the trick.  It needs to be an anchor tag.  I suspect it's because the anchor tag actually has some visible component to its focus, which resets something in firefox's internal cursor display mechanism.

Either way, if you're trying to solve problems like this and this doesn't fix it, look at MorganTiley's explanation -- that might give you some good leads.

Comment: Fantastic. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for ages. This works for me. Other questions and answers attempt to select a range of text, but that wasn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you load the content, you are changing the structure of the html nodes and thus invalidating the selection (a cursor is just a collapsed selection). I recommend trying to reset it via [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). It works well in combination with jquery. Use jquery to get the first element in your contentEditable area, e.g. the first paragraph, then make a new rangy range and select that paragraph (node) and collapse to start. This will put the cursor at the very beginning of your content. Here's some rough code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //init rangy
});

function ajaxLoaded {
  var p = $(".contenteditablediv p:first")[0];
  var sel = rangy.getSelection();
  sel.collapse(p, 0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Rangy didn't solve my problem, although your explanation provided some valuable insight into selections.  Thanks.

Comment: what happened? can you give more context? e.g. any other scripts you have running on the page or how the html is set up? Rangy should definitely be able to move the cursor to anywhere you want.

Comment: There are a number of other scripts running on the page, but I've made sure that all of my selection/alteration code (the rangy code you posted) occurs after all the other scripts have completed.  

Honestly, my problem probably lies somewhere deep in the external javascript that I'm loading.  I'll have to do some more digging.  Either way, I feel like Firefox should be smart enough to be able to reset my cursor anyway, so perhaps this is a bug I should log with them.

I do appreciate your input, though.

Comment: No problem. I've been working on editor for more than a year now and I know it can be painful. I doubt it's firefox though. Do some more experimentation. create a test page with the simplest functionality possible and see if it still occurs. Also try appending the ajax result to the contentEditable section (maybe with some default content on load) and see what happens. And do some experimentation with Rangy. If you're making this xbrowser compatible I'd say it's almost essential to use it. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisJ: I'd happily dual license Rangy but Google Code doesn't allow it. Which license would suit you better? I'm open to moving Rangy's hosting elsewhere if licensing is a problem.

Comment: Sorry Tim!  Turns out, I knew next to nothing about licenses when I posted that comment.  I didn't realize MIT was permissive -- I thought it was a GPL-style license.  If we run into any further cursors issues, I'll definitely take another look at your library.